# How to convert a decimal into it's time equivalent as part of a function?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time, compare, google-sheets-formula

I'm running into an issue when trying to compare data across two sheets to find discrepancies - specifically when it comes to comparing start and end times.

Right now, the "IF" statement in my screenshot is executing perfectly, except when a time is involved - it's reading those cells as decimals instead (but only sometimes).

I've tried formatting these cells (on the raw data AND on this "Discrepancies" report sheet) so that they are displayed as a "HH:MM am/pm" time, but the sheet is still comparing the decimal values.

Is there anything that I can add to this function to account for a compared value being a time instead of text, and having that text be compared for any discrepancies? I cannot add or change anything to the raw data sheets, the only thing I can edit is the formula seen in the screenshot I provided.

See the highlighted cells in my screenshot - this is the issue I keep running into. As you can see, there are SOME cells (the non-highlighted ones) that are executing as intended, but I'm unsure why this isn't the case for the whole spreadsheet when I've formatted everything the same way using the exact same formula across the whole sheet.

For example, the values in cell N2 is "8:00 AM" on both sheets, so the formula should just display "8:00 AM" in that cell (and NOT be highlighted) since there is no discrepancy in the cells between both sheets it's comparing. But instead, it's showing both times as a decimal with the slightest difference between them and is suggesting a difference where there technically isn't (or shouldn't be) one.

Please help!

[Screenshot of original spreadsheet for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLe7f.png)

---EDIT (added the below):

Here is a view-only version of a SAMPLE SHEET that displays the issue I'm having:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BdSQGsCajB3kOnYxzM3sl-0o3iTvR3ABdHpnzYRXjpA/edit?usp=sharing

On the sample sheet, the only cells that are performing as intended are C2, E2, G2, I2, K2, K6, or any cells that contain text like "Closed". Any of the other cells that have a time in both raw data tabs appears to be pulling the serial numbers for those times instead of correctly formatting it into "HH:mm AM/PM".

A quick tour of how the SAMPLE SHEET is set up:

1. User enters raw data into the "MicrositeRawData" and "SalesforceRawData" tabs.
2. Data is pulled from the "SalesforceRawData" tab into the "CleanedUpSalesforceData" tab using a QUERY that matches the UNIQUE ID's from the "MicrositeRawData" sheet, so that it essentially creates a tab that's in the same order and accounts for any extraneous data between the tabs (keep in mind this is a sample sheet and that the original sheet I'm using includes a lot more data which causes a mismatch of rows between the sheets which makes the QUERY necessary).
3. The "DISCREPANCIES" tab then compares the data between the "MicrositeRawData" and "CleanedUpSalesforceData" tabs. If the data is the same, it simply copies the data from the "MicrositeRawData" cell. But if the data is NOT the same, it lists the values from both sheets and is conditionally formatted to highlight those cells in yellow.
4. If there is data on the "MicrositeRawData" tab that is NOT included on the "SalesforceRawData" tab, the "DISCREPANCIES" tab will notate that and highlight the "A" cell in pink instead of yellow (as demonstrated in "A5").

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: @player0 Please see the edit - I added a sample sheet along with an explanation for how things function. Thank you for looking into this and any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in B2:

```
=IF(MicrositeRawData!B2=CleanedUpSalesforceData!B2, MicrositeRawData!B2,
 "MICROSITE: "&TEXT(MicrositeRawData!B2, "h:mm AM/PM")&CHAR(10)&
 "SALESFORCE: "&TEXT(CleanedUpSalesforceData!B2, "h:mm AM/PM"))
```

[image]

---

### update

delete all formulae from range B2:O10 and use this in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TO_TEXT(MicrositeRawData!B2:O10)=
 TO_TEXT(CleanedUpSalesforceData!B2:O10), MicrositeRawData!B2:O10,
 "MICROSITE: "&TEXT(IF(MicrositeRawData!B2:O10="", 
 "", MicrositeRawData!B2:O10), "h:mm AM/PM")&CHAR(10)&
 "SALESFORCE: "&TEXT(IF(CleanedUpSalesforceData!B2:O10="", 
 "", CleanedUpSalesforceData!B2:O10), "h:mm AM/PM")))
```

[image]

Comment: That almost fixed it, thank you for this! You definitely helped to fix the formatting issue, but there are two other things wrong with this sheet. I used your formula on all cells (B2:O10), but if you look at rows "4, 6, 7", all of those times are the same in each cell so it SHOULD be displaying the same way that "C2, E2, G2, I2, K2, K6" currently are. Also, in row "5", the "CleanedUpSalesforceData" is blank but somehow it's pulling in "12:00 AM" as the time? Is there any way to fix the cells that have matching values, and have the "12:00 AM" return as empty after "SALESFORCE:"?

Comment: @Jon answer updated

Comment: That's PERFECT! Thank you so much!